# Why does gbm() give different results than h2o.gbm() in this minimal example?

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o, gbm

Tinkering with gradient boosting and I noticed R's `gbm` package produces different results than `h2o` on a minimal example.  Why?

---

**Data**

```
library(gbm)
library(h2o)

h2o.init()

train <- data.frame(
  X1 = factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B")),
  X2 = factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B")),
  Y = c(0, 1, 3, 4, 7)
)
  X1 X2 Y
1  A  A 0
2  A  A 1
3  A  B 3
4  B  B 4
5  B  B 7
```

**gbm**

```
# (gbm, 1 round, mae)
model.gbm <- gbm(
  Y ~ X1 + X2, data = train, distribution="laplace", n.tree = 1, shrinkage = 1, n.minobsinnode=1, bag.fraction=1, 
  interaction.depth = 1, verbose=TRUE
)
train$Pred.mae.gbm1 <- predict(model.gbm, newdata=train, n.trees=model.gbm$n.trees)
```

**h2o**

```
# (h2o, 1 round, mae)
model.h2o <- h2o.gbm(
  x=c("X1", "X2"), y="Y", training_frame=as.h2o(train), distribution="laplace", ntrees=1, max_depth=1, 
  learn_rate = 1, min_rows=1
)
train$Pred.mae.h2o1 <- as.data.frame(h2o.predict(model.h2o, as.h2o(train)))$predict
```

**Results**

```
train
  X1 X2 Y Pred.mae.gbm1 Pred.mae.h2o1
1  A  A 0           1.0           0.5
2  A  A 1           1.0           0.5
3  A  B 3           1.0           4.0
4  B  B 4           5.5           4.0
5  B  B 7           5.5           4.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are completely independent implementations, and I doubt either has been tuned or designed with the way you are using it in mind (i.e. a single tree, `min_rows` set to 1). In this case it looks like R's gbm has used its single tree on learning the "B" inputs correctly, while `h2o.gbm` has concentrated on the "A" inputs.

When you start using real data and real settings, there may still be differences. There are a lot of parameters you are not touching (with `h2o.gbm()` at least, which is the one I'm familiar with). And there is also a stochastic element: try a hundred values of `seed` to h2o.gbm(), and a constant `set.seed()` before R's `gbm`, and you will likely hit the same results on at least one of them.